# Загвоздка с получением среднего значения в yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Ситуация следующая, есть модель:

```
class Comment extends ActiveRecord {

    public static function tableName(){ //указываем нужное название таблицы
        return 'comments';
    }

    public function getRating(){
        return $this->hasMany(Rating::className(), ['comment_id' => 'id']);
    }

    private function children(){
        return $this->hasMany($this, ['parent' => 'id']);
    }

    protected function getTree(){
        return $this->children()->with('tree', 'rating');
    }

    public static function getTreeComment(){
        return Comment::find()
            ->where(["parent" => null])
            ->with(['tree', 'rating'])
            ->all();
    }

}
```

С помощью данного кода получаю древо комментариев, все работает хорошо, так же получаем все оценки кто ставил на какой комментарий. Но на выходе я хочу получить не массив оценок, а только среднее значение. Делаю так :

```
public function getRating(){
     return $this->hasMany(Rating::className(), ['comment_id' => 'id'])->average('rating');
}
```

но получаю ошибку:

```
app\models\Comment has no relation named "rating".
```

что делаю не так?

Comment: Попробуй `->average('tableName.rating');`

Comment: @fedornabilkin к сожалению, нет, не сработало(

Comment: Можно среднее вычислить после выборки. Например https://github.com/yii2mod/collection#avg

Comment: @fedornabilkin спасибо. уже вручную подсчеты сделали)))) щас на либу переделаем) спасибо еще раз